# Invalid Syntax Error On Simple Integer Assignment

Tags: python, variables, syntax, integer, variable-assignment

I think I'm running into encoding issues. When I change to utf-16 the error changes to the first line "import temperature"

I installed Python 3.x thinking maybe it was a version issue but same symptoms.

Other exercise scripts I've been running have worked fine. Any ideas?

Python indicates the syntax error occurs at "temp = 0"

##### modules.py file

```
import temperature

temp = 212
convTemp = temperature.ftoc(temp)
print("The converted temp is " + str(convTemp))
temp = 0
convTemp = temperature.ctof(temp)
print("The converted temp is " + str(convTemp))
```

#### temperature.py file contents

```
def ftoc(temp):
    return (5.0/9.0) * (temp - 32.0)

def ctof(temp):
    return (9.0/5.0) * temp + 32.0
```

Results after correcting code from original post.

```
hostname$ python modules.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "modules.py", line 1, in <module>
    import temperature
  File "/Users/[myusername]/Dropbox/python/temperature.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xfe' in file /Users/[myusername]/Dropbox/python/temperature.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
hostname$
```

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis on the previous line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be encoding problem, indeed. The `\xFE` is part of [**BOM**(`\xFE \xFF`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) for UTF-16 encodings.

Using UTF-16 as Python source code is not a good idea. You're not able to give Python parser a hint of the source code encoding of the source file using the encoding mark. Such as

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

See [`PEP-0263`](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) for detailed explanation, and below is part of important information:

> Any encoding which allows processing the first two lines in the way indicated above is allowed as source code encoding, **this includes ASCII compatible encodings as well as certain multi-byte encodings such as Shift_JIS. It does not include encodings which use two or more bytes for all characters like e.g. UTF-16**. The reason for this is to keep the encoding detection algorithm in the tokenizer simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
from temperature import ftoc
from temperature import ctof
```

This is redundant because you imported all the temperature functions with

```
import temperature
```

You have syntax errors, missing parens at the end of your print statements.

Also you have `str(temperature)` when you want `str(convTemp)`. Fix these things and I think it will work fine.

Comment: That was embarrassing.  Sorry. Long day.  This is where the encoding error seems to become more apparent.

Comment: 'code'hostname$ python modules.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "modules.py", line 1, in <module>
    import temperature
  File "/Users/[myusername]/Dropbox/python/temperature.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xfe' in file /Users/[myusername]/Dropbox/python/temperature.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
hostname$

Comment: The modified program worked for me just copy pasting from your question and editing what you had in a text editor - I didn't get encoding errors.

Comment: Using TextWrangler with UTF-8 as the default. I encountered similar errors using the requests module until I came across a thread to import sys; reload(sys); sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8") which resolved my issue but seemed a bit much.

Comment: You're just missing a parenthesis.  don't bother with changing the default encoding.  that just causes more problems with libraries expecting the default to be `ascii` on Python 2.X.  On 3.X `utf-8` is already the default.

Comment: @user3594743 Also, `utf-16` isn't a supported source encoding, see [PEP 0263](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

Comment: I'm not deliberately trying to change encoding except for troubleshooting. In fact, I ran the code above without any "encode/decode" statements and that was the error I encountered. Could my mac default be causing this? Does Python use my default encoding?  I would think it would stay a utf default?  I appreciate everyones help here. Thank you all for the quick responses.

Comment: The program works fine for me in both python 2.7 and python 3 with ascii encoding. Why not just save the file as ascii?

Comment: >>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
>>>   # What affect does my system defaulting to ascii have on my python code and editors? I thought Python would default to unicode like I save in my editors?

Comment: I checked python3 and the default is correctly utf-8. 2.x docs indicate 'ascii' is the default.  No problems there, but something funky is happening.  Missing ending print statement parents corrected.

Comment: SOLUTION: Cleaned up syntactical errors noted above by these kind folks.  The last error indicating non-ascii character was due to the temperature module being saved as utf-16 in TextWrangler.  Changed to utf-8 and all was well with the world. You are the keepers of the Holy Grail.  But I am tired.